# Owl Carousel 2 - caption div (img title & alt tags)

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I'm looking for a way to display the `img` title & `alt` tags in a `div` (`.image-caption`).

This is my code so far:

```
    owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {

        var comment = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
        var title = $(this).find('img').attr('title');
        if(comment) $('#desktop .image-caption').html('<h4>'+title+'</h4><p>'+comment+'</p>');

    })
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Isnt this working?? Whats the problem u r facing?

Comment: For some reason the .image-caption won’t retreive the alt and title tags, that come with the active image. The .image-caption is placed outside the Owl Carousel.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in fiddle and share?

Comment: Sure, find it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Schakelen/wx0ovpzh/45/

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions;  this question is not about OWL, the Web Ontology Language.  The tag description for [tag:owl] says "The Web Ontology Language (OWL) is a vocabulary for creating schemas (ontologies), i.e. definitions of classes, properties and the relationships between them."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `translated.owl.carousel` event for that

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/3k4k23dn/)

```
owl.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {
     var comment = $(this).find('.active').find('img').attr('alt');
    var title = $(this).find('.active').find('img').attr('title');
    if(comment) $('.image-caption').html('<h4>'+title+'</h4><p>'+comment+'</p>');
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Slightly improved code and added functionality to update image caption on carousel load.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/3k4k23dn/2/)

Comment: Thanks Cerlin! Works great! I've posted another question concerning the Owl Carousel's autoHeight and multiple items: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769409/owl-carousel-2-autoheight-multiple-items

Comment: You have a typo in your improved fiddle. In the CSS file it must be `width: 100%;` and not `widht` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
var comment = $(this).find('.active').find('img').attr('alt');
var title = $(this).find('.active').find('img').attr('title');
if(comment) $('.image-caption').html('<h4>'+title+'</h4><p>'+comment+'</p>');
```

try it: https://jsfiddle.net/wx0ovpzh/49/

Comment: Thanks! But this method is still not accurate. When I change the slide the .image-caption will retrieve its data from the previous image..