# Owl Carousel 2 - autoHeight (multiple items)

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

At the moment the Owl Carousel autoHeight works only with 1 item on screen. Their plan is to calculate all visible items and change height according to highest item.

I work around this problem by calling the .active classes on the visible items, and give the invisible items a small height. Is there already a more elegant solution?

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop: true,
items: 3,
margin: 1,
autoHeight: true,
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Schakelen/bxkpmojs/)

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't using yours `style="height : 450px"` and set this value for all the div ?

Comment: I'm using images with different heights and I don't want the whitespace to appear underneath the carousel.

Comment: You need to set a height to the hole OwlCarousel, or to its items ?

Comment: The height of the Owl Carousel needs to be the same as the height of the highest visible image, and update itself on the go..

Answer (score 18):

I'm not sure if anyone is still looking for solutions for this problem in 2020, but after trying a lot of things that didn't work, I found a very simple one. It's all about setting no height to the item that's not active.

Like so:

```
.owl-item {height: 0;}    
.owl-item.active {height: auto;}
```

It's elegant and no javascript is needed. You can even play with transitions to set some cool animations.

I hope I have helped someone here.

PS: To use this method, keep autoHeight: false ... otherwise the carousel height will be set to 0 by the library

Comment: brilliant! worth mentioning to keep autoHeight: false, otherwise the height of all items will be 0.

Comment: can you show an example of how to add transition animation please?

Comment: you are a LIFESAVER!!!!!! and yes, someone in 2020 was looking!

Comment: Simply solution but it works like a charm!!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

I solved it via the internal API using several events calling the same autoHeight-function.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxkpmojs/51/)

The jQuery-Part:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    items: 3,
    margin: 1,
    autoHeight: true,
    onInitialized: setOwlStageHeight,
    onResized: setOwlStageHeight,
    onTranslated: setOwlStageHeight
});
function setOwlStageHeight(event) {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('.owl-item.active').each(function () { // LOOP THROUGH ACTIVE ITEMS
        var thisHeight = parseInt( $(this).height() );
        maxHeight=(maxHeight>=thisHeight?maxHeight:thisHeight);
    });
    $('.owl-carousel').css('height', maxHeight );
    $('.owl-stage-outer').css('height', maxHeight ); // CORRECT DRAG-AREA SO BUTTONS ARE CLICKABLE
}
```

For enabling the height-animation I added the following CSS:

```
.owl-carousel,
.owl-stage-outer { transition: height 500ms ease-in-out 0s; }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your great help!! It works nicely, when the item has a given height. 

Is it possible to scale the stageHeight, according to dynamic item heights? And is there a way to initialize the stageHeight with the height of the first item (on page load)?

https://jsfiddle.net/Schakelen/y18074c0/

Comment: I don´t understand as your Fiddle already works with dynamic item heights, I cannot find any fixed heights. And yes, you can init the stageHeight by the first item´s height by using the jQuery :first-selector. [https://jsfiddle.net/y18074c0/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/y18074c0/5/)

Answer (score 2):

I used flex to solve this issue:

```
 .owl-stage {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

above code for `owl-stage` and below for `owl-item` class:

```
.owl-item{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

I hope this reply help every body that have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I only resolved adding a autoWidth:true,  and it works now!

My owl script is:

```
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: false,
  margin: 10,
  items: 1,
  autoHeight: true,
  autoWidth: true,
  nav: true,
  navText: [
    "<i class='fa fa-caret-left'></i>",
    "<i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i>"
  ],
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 3
    },
    1000: {
      items: 5
    }
  }
})
```