# How to add captions for images in owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

I'm using own carousel, so to add caption I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751878/owl-carousel-2-caption-div-img-title-alt-tags) on stack overflow but it didn't work for me. Then I checked using inspect element and found that their is no 'active' class on my carousel current image. So I added script to do so. In the end my script look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        items: 1,
        afterAction: function(el) {
            //remove class active
            this
                .$owlItems
                .removeClass('active')

            //add class active
            this
                .$owlItems
                .eq(this.currentItem)
                .addClass('active')
        },

        onInitialized: function() {
            var activeImg = $('.owl-carousel').find('.active').find('img');
            var comment = activeImg.attr('alt');
            var title = activeImg.attr('title');
            if (comment) $('.image-caption').html('<h4>' + title + '</h4><p>' + comment + '</p>');
        }
    });

    owl = $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
    $('.prev').click(function() {
        owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
    });
    $('.next').click(function() {
        owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
    });

    owl.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {
        var activeImg = $(this).find('.active').find('img');
        var comment = activeImg.attr('alt');
        var title = activeImg.attr('title');
        if (comment) $('.image-caption').html('<h4>' + title + '</h4><p>' + comment + '</p>');
    });
});
```

The script is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution i am using [HTML figcaption](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) element that represents a caption or a legend associated with a [HTML figure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure).

Also i have added all the needed logic at [OWL Carousel](http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) `afterMove` after move callback:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    items: 1,
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true,
    lazyLoad: true,
    singleItem: true,
    afterMove: function(elem) {
        var current = this.currentItem;
        var currentImg = elem.find('.owl-item').eq(current).find('img');

        $('figure')
            .find('img')
            .attr({
                'src': currentImg.attr('src'),
                'alt': currentImg.attr('alt'),
                'title': currentImg.attr('title')
            });
        $('#figcaption').text(currentImg.attr('title'));
    }
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    display: block;
    width:80%;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.transitions.min.css" />

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<figure id="currentImageWithCaption">
    <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg" title="Title 1" alt="Title 1" width="50" height="30">
    <figcaption id="figcaption">Title 1</figcaption>
</figure>

<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg" title="Title 1" alt="Alt 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg" title="Title 2" alt="Alt 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg" title="Title 3" alt="Alt 3" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg" title="Title 4" alt="Alt 4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We don't need <figure>...</figure>. Instead of showing an another image just set image title to <figcaption></figcaption> in this way we can show only caption for the current image.

Comment: You should give a read to `HTML <figure>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure But now you can configure your script as you prefer for your solution

Answer (score 1):

@YosvelQuintero posted the script but don't know why he deleted it. So I am posting it again in case if anybody need it.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.transitions.min.css" />

<figure id="currentImageWithCaption">
    <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg" title="Title 1" alt="Title 1" width="200" height="150">
    <figcaption id="figcaption">Title 1</figcaption>
</figure>

<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg" title="Title 1" alt="Alt 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg" title="Title 2" alt="Alt 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg" title="Title 3" alt="Alt 3" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg" title="Title 4" alt="Alt 4" />
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<style>
figure img {
display: block;
width:100%;
height: auto;
}
.owl-wrapper-outer{
    display : none;
}
</style>

<script>
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        items: 1,
        navigation: true,
        pagination: true,
        lazyLoad: true,
        afterMove: function(elem) {
            var current = this.currentItem;
            var currentImg = elem.find('.owl-item').eq(current).find('img');

            $('figure')
                .find('img')
                .attr('src', currentImg.attr('src'))
                .attr('alt', currentImg.attr('alt'))
                .attr('title', currentImg.attr('title'));
            $('#figcaption').text(currentImg.attr('title'));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Updated my response